# Binding to TemplatedParent within a ControlTemplate.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ControlTemplate` in which I would like to take in two collections and combine them into one collection which would then be bound to an `ItemsControl`.The calculation is done by the `Calculator` object, which I create an instance of within the `ResourceDictionary` of the template.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IndicatorBar}">
       <ControlTemplate.Resources>
          <local:Calculator 
            x:Key="_calculator"
            Ranges="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Ranges}" 
            DataSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataSource}" />
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Ratios, Source={StaticResource _calculator}}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Border Background="{Binding Range}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ratio}" Foreground="White" />
              </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

However, this does not seem to work and causes binding errors:

> *System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>
>   BindingExpression:Path=Ranges; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'Calculator' (HashCode=33746798); target property is 'Ranges' (type
>   'Ranges')
>
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataSource; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'Calculator' (HashCode=33746798); target property is 'DataSource'
>   (type 'IEnumerable')*

I'm unsure of how I can get around this issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your error says the targetElement is "Calculator", yet your ControlTemplate is typed towards "local:IndicatorBar".  How do these two objects relate in your tree?

Comment: There's too little code to describe the context. Please post how you use this Template (e.g. the IndicatorBar type used in XAML) and the code where you set its Ranges  and DataSource property.

Comment: If you have the source to calculator then I would probably just make it as a multi value converter that takes the two collections as parameters. Then you can do your ItemsSource binding passing the converter along with it.

Comment: Ranges and Datasource property in Calculator class are dependency property?

Comment: @BillTarbell If you see in the XAML, I have a calculator that is processing the input to the control and then the Border is bound to the output of the calculator.

Comment: @CodeMonkey This is a lookless control, the only code there really is is the Template XAML

Comment: @Andy This is what I'm doing temporarily to progress with my work, but it is quite slow due to the fact that the converter has to process the entire input every time, both of which are collections, where as with the calculator I would be able to store state and optimise it after the initial binding is complete.

Comment: @DJ Yes, both properties are Dependency properties.

Answer (score 0):

At first, your binding using **RelativeSource.TemplatedParent** mode so the source of the binding is the control that you apply this template. I don't think **TemplatedParent** is suitable for your case. 
Please refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for **TemplatedParent** use.
Could you add your model which contains your data for binding to Calculator control?